# how to insert multiple values in database using CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, insert

I tried to insert multiple data values in mysql database using codeignitor. But its not working

I got the following error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvHT6.png)
[db error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYJ1o.png)

```
INSERT INTO `allocated` (0, 1) VALUES ('1463104690','9443610181'), ('Timing-Device Piston','Pump element '), ('Bosch Germany','Bosch Germany'), ('17.07.2019','17.07.2019'), ('17.07.2019','17.07.2019'), ('Nigeria','Nigeria'), ('AGL-0014','AGL-0014'), ('302-05861181-19','302-05861181-19'), ('142417201432','142417201432'), ('84139100','84139100'), ('INDIA','JAPAN'), ('20','24'), ('',''), ('20','24'), ('10','14'), ('20',''), ('21.52','14.7'), ('',''), ('',''), ('',''), ('215.2','205.8'), ('0.056','0.136'), ('0.56','1.904'), ('',''), ('',''), ('',''), (), ('3785174','351715735'), ('xyz','abc')
```

Filename: D:/wamp/www/aal-stock/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Controller:

```
function itemsallocated()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('Username') != '')
        {
            $this->load->model("main_model");
            $pn=$this->input->post('Part_Number');
            $desc=$this->input->post('Description');
            $brand=$this->input->post('From');
            //$pfrom=$this->input->post('From');
            $idate=$this->input->post('Date');
            $impcode=$this->input->post('Import_License_Number');

            $invused=$this->input->post('Invoice_Used');
            $invno=$this->input->post('Invoice_Number');
            $decno=$this->input->post('Declaration_Number');
            $billno=$this->input->post('Bill_Number');

            $hscode=$this->input->post('HS_Code');
            $coo=$this->input->post('COO');
            $qty=$this->input->post('Quantity');
            $Stock_Rem=$this->input->post('Stock_Rem');
            $Stock_Rem2=$this->input->post('Stock_Rem2');
            $cart=$this->input->post('cart');
            $Allocated=$this->input->post('Allocated');


            $euro=$this->input->post('Price_in_Euro');
            $usd=$this->input->post('Price_in_USD');
            $aed=$this->input->post('AED');
            $jpy=$this->input->post('JPY');

            $value=$this->input->post('Value');
            $wpp=$this->input->post('Wt_Per_Piece');
            $twt=$this->input->post('Total_Wt');

            $L=$this->input->post('L');
            $B=$this->input->post('B');
            $H=$this->input->post('H');

            $Added_By=$this->input->post('Added_By');
            $Cus_Name=$this->input->post('Cus_Name');

            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
            $ddate= date('d-m-Y H:i:s');


    $data=array('Part_Number'=>$pn,
                'Description'=>$this->input->post('Description'),
                'From'=>$brand,
                'Date'=>$idate,

                'Import_License_Number'=>$impcode,
                'Invoice_Used'=>$invused,
                'Invoice_Number'=>$invno,
                'Declaration_Number'=>$decno,

                'Bill_Number'=>$billno,
                'HS_Code'=>$hscode,
                'COO'=>$coo,
                'Quantity'=>$qty,

                'Stock_Rem'=>$Stock_Rem,
                'Stock_Rem2'=>$Stock_Rem2,
                'cart'=>$cart,
                'Allocated'=>$Allocated,


                'Price_in_Euro'=>$euro,
                'Price_in_USD'=>$usd,
                'AED'=>$aed,
                'JPY'=>$jpy,
                'Value'=>$value,
                'Wt_Per_Piece'=>$wpp,
                'Total_Wt'=>$twt,

                'L'=>$L,
                'B'=>$B,
                'H'=>$H,

                'd_t'=>$ddate,
                'Added_By'=>$Added_By,
                'Cus_Name'=>$Cus_Name


                );

$this->db->insert_batch('allocated', $data);
```

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message

Answer (score 2):

to insert multiple data values in CodeIgniter:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(`enter code here`
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data)
{
  $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - you should highlight that this solution has serious drawbacks if a lot of data is inserted